# Показ видео при открытии страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, видео

Вот HTML

```
            <div class="video_wrapp" style="background-image: url(video/videobg.jpg);">
                <video poster="video/videobg.jpg" id="promoVideo" class="loadVideo">
                    <source src="video/video.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
                    <source src="video/video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
                    <source src="video/video.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
                    Тег video не поддерживается вашим браузером. 
                    <a href="video/video.mp4">Скачайте видео</a>.
                </video>
            </div>
```

Нужно при загрузке страницы видео не показывается, а показывается фон poster="video/videobg.jpg".
Как сделать так чтобы при открытии страницы показывалось видео и сразу проигрывалось.

Comment: Добавьте в тэг <video> аттрибут autoplay="autoplay"

Comment: И когда будете это делать, подумайте как обеспечить, чтобы люди, зайдя на эту страницу, не поминали Вас или вашего заказчика недобрым словом

Comment: не сработало. Видео не показывается а видно постер.

Comment: точнее видео не запускается без очистки кеша

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду под "видео не запускается без очистки кеша"? Откройте в приватной вкладке или нажмите Ctrl+Shift+R.
P.S. @SergeyNudnov прав. Заставлять пользователя смотреть видео сразу по приходу на страницу - плохая практика, особенно в странах СНГ, где траффик и скорость мобильного интернета ограничена. Рекомендуется минимизировать размер видео - сжать, перегнать в gif и т.д.

Comment: Нечего не могу сделать так заказчик хочет, хотя могу ему об этом сказать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Атрибут autoplay="autoplay" нужно поставить в начале тега video.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте к видео атрибут muted, браузер может блокировать воспроисзведение из-за звука( даже если его там нет).
p.s борьба с недобросовестными сайтами

```
<video muted> ... <video>
<video muted=""> ... <video>
<video muted="muted"> ... <video>
```